# I can't figure out why my program isn't printing when I run it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-statements, println

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with some homework as I'm a beginner. I simplified the code to try and troubleshoot a smaller portion. I can't get this to print anything.

I'm pretty sure this stems from a problem within the `addStudent`method. I think that it's not printing because the `if (stud != null)` conditional is returning true and not allowing it to get to the `if (numStudents < MAX_STUDENTS)` that would actually add the students.

I can't get rid of the `if (stud != null)` or change the order in which the conditionals are in. If I do, then I get the nullPointerException due to the stud pointing to nothing.

Please help. I don't know what else to try.

This is the simplified code. (sorry about the indentation, I don't know how to put it in to this nicely)

```
public class Foothill
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       int k;

       //set up even group of new students
       Student [] myClass={
           new Student ("Calvo", "Emmet", 125),
           new Student ("Yamaguchi", "Carlin", 343),
           new Student ("Ung", "Cari", 42),
           new Student ("Tweedy", "Jasper", 202),
           new Student ("Lorenz", "3rma", 912),
           new Student ("0Rlando", "Brandee", 50),
           new Student ("Swindell", "Mavis", 936),
           new Student ("Sugibayashi", "Nora", 231),
           new Student ("Ching", "Gavin", 269),
       };

       // instantiate a StudArrUtilObject
       StudentArrayUtilities myStuds = new StudentArrayUtilities();

       // we can add students manually and individually
       myStuds.addStudent( new Student("bartman", "petra", 102));
       myStuds.addStudent( new Student("charters", "rodney", 295));

       // if we happen to have an array available, we can add students in loop.
       for (k = 0; k < myClass.length; k++)
           myStuds.addStudent( myClass[k] );

       System.out.println(myStuds.toString("Before:"));
   }
}

class Student
{
     //declare members
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int totalPoints;

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "zz-error";
    public static final int DEFAULT_POINTS = 0; 
    public static final int MAX_POINTS = 1000;

    // constructor requires parameters - no default supplied
    public Student(String last, String first, int points)
    {
       if ( !setLastName(last) )
          lastName = DEFAULT_NAME;
       if ( !setFirstName(first) )
          firstName = DEFAULT_NAME;
       if ( !setPoints(points) )
          totalPoints = DEFAULT_POINTS;    
    }

    //accessor methods
    public String getLastName()
    {
      return lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() 
    { 
       return firstName; 
    }
    public int getTotalPoints()
    {
       return totalPoints;
    }

    //mutator methods
    boolean setLastName(String last)
    {
       if ( !validString(last) )
          return false;
       lastName = last;
       return true;
    }
    boolean setFirstName(String first)
    {
       if ( !validString(first) )
          return false;
       firstName = first;
       return true;
    }
    boolean setPoints(int pts)
    {
       if ( !validPoints(pts) )
          return false;
       totalPoints = pts;
       return true;
    }

    //tells caller what to print
    public String toString()
    {
       String resultString;

       resultString = " "+ lastName 
          + ", " + firstName
          + " points: " + totalPoints
          + "\n";
       return resultString;
    }  

    //checks for valid inputs
    private boolean validString( String testStr )
    {
       if (testStr != null && Character.isLetter(testStr.charAt(0)))
          return true;
       return false;
    } 
    private boolean validPoints( int testPoints )
    {
       if (testPoints >= 0 && testPoints <= MAX_POINTS)
          return true;
       return false;
    }
}

class StudentArrayUtilities
{
    //members
    public int numStudents;
    public Student [] theArray;

    final int MAX_STUDENTS = 20;

    // print the array with string
    public String toString(String title)
    {
        String output = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < numStudents; k++)
            output += "title"+ theArray[k].toString();
        return output;
    }

    public boolean addStudent( Student stud )
    {
        if (stud != null)
            return true;
        if (numStudents < MAX_STUDENTS)
        {
            theArray[numStudents] = stud;
            numStudents++;
            return true;
        }
        else
             return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: By ***far*** the best way to deal with this code not working is to **run the code using the debugger built into your IDE**. You'll be able to step through the logic, statement by statement, inspect variables, etc. **Using a debugger is not an advanced skill**, it's a basic skill and primary development tool. Once you've written "Hello, world" for the first time, your very next step should be to use the debugger to learn how to debug things.

Comment: The course I'm currently taking did not include this in the content but I'll make sure to look into this. It seems like a great resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a constructor to your StudentArrayUtilities class in order to initialize the array and the numStudents variable:

```
public StudentArrayUtilities() {
    numStudents = 0;
    theArray = new Student[MAX_STUDENTS];
}
```

Furthermore I've edited your addStudent method because it's wrong to return true if stud != null:

```
public boolean addStudent( Student stud )
  {
      if (stud == null)
         return false;

      if (numStudents < MAX_STUDENTS)
      {
         theArray[numStudents] = stud;
         numStudents++;
         return true;
      }

      return false;
 }
```

After this output:

> title bartman, petra points: 102 title charters, rodney points: 295
>   title Calvo, Emmet points: 125 title Yamaguchi, Carlin points: 343
>   title Ung, Cari points: 42 title Tweedy, Jasper points: 202 title
>   Lorenz, zz-error points: 912 title zz-error, Brandee points: 50 title
>   Swindell, Mavis points: 936 title Sugibayashi, Nora points: 231 title
>   Ching, Gavin points: 269

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm just not sure if I'm allowed to add a constructor as it's not in the spec. (but I get points as long as the program runs, so this is helpful)

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe The constructors are the base of OOP, so I guess that you can add it :) Please vote up my answer

Comment: The checkmark is the upvote? I thought it was the ^ arrow (which than told me I'm not a reputable source). Sorry about that, I just clicked the checkmark

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe it's ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this here is wrong:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student stud) {
    if (stud != null)
        return true;
    if (numStudents < MAX_STUDENTS) {
        theArray[numStudents] = stud;
        numStudents++;
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

specifically this:

```
if (stud != null)
        return true;
```

that is causing that your method returns `true` everytime your student parameter is different from null, at the end, that condition is the reason why:

`numStudents` never get increased

and why

this code

```
 for (int k = 0; k < numStudents; k++)
        output += "title" + theArray[k].toString();
```

is same as

```
 for (int k = 0; k < 0; k++)
        output += "title" + theArray[k].toString();
```

ergo:

`output` never changes its initial value `""` (empty string) and that is what you are printing at the end (you are actually printing, but printing an empty string)...

Comment: thanks for answering so promptly. I kind of figured that was the issue but what I can't figure out is how to make it work without it. I can't get rid of the if (stud != null) or change the order in which the conditionals are in. If I do, then I get the nullPointerException due to the stud reference pointing to nothing.

Comment: change this: ***if (stud != null)
        return true;*** with this: ***if (stud == null)
        return false;***

Comment: you may need to modify some logic after that

Answer (score 0):

I think your method should look like this:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student stud) {
    if (stud != null && numStudents < MAX_STUDENTS) {
        theArray[numStudents] = stud;
        numStudents++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also skip maintaining numStudents and try to use theArray.lenght instead.

Comment: I actually tried both these options... It still gives me the nullpointerexception error.

Comment: it's this line "if (stud != null && theArray.length < MAX_STUDENTS) {"

Comment: Right.. because theArray is null :-)
     public Student [] theArray = new Student [MAX_STUDENTS];

Comment: sorry, I've edited previous comment. Try the above. :-)

Comment: At first it just outputted "Before". But I changed it back to numStudents instead of theArray.length and it worked. Thanks for working through this with me!